# implement an integration math equation using odeint in Python

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the following equation in python using the scipy.odeint function.

[image: equation 1]

Currently I am able to implement this form of the equation

[image: equation 2]

in python using the following script:

```
def dY(y1, x):
    a = 0.001
    yin = 1
    C = 0.01
    N = 1
    dC = C/N
    b1 = 0
    return (a/dC)*(yin-y1)+b1*dC

x = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
y0 = 0
res = odeint(dY, y0, x)
plt.plot(t,res, '-')
plt.show()
```

My problem with the first equation is 'i'. I don't know how to integrate the equation and still be able to provide the current and previous 'y'(yi-1 and yi) values. 'i' is simply a sequence number that is within a range of 0..100.

Edit 1:

The original equation is:
[image: Original equation]

Which I rewrote using y,x,a,b and C

Edit2:
I edited Pierre de Buyl' code and changed the N value. Luckily I have a validation table to validate the outcome against. Unfortunately, the results are not equal.

Here is my validation table:

[image: Validation image]

and here is the numpy output:

[image: numpy output]

Used code:

```
def dY(y, x):
    a = 0.001
    yin = 1
    C = 0.01
    N = 3
    dC = C/N
    b1 = 0.01
    y_diff = -np.copy(y)
    y_diff[0] += yin
    y_diff[1:] += y[:-1]
    return (a/dC)*(y_diff)+b1*dC

x = np.linspace(0,20,11)
y0 = np.zeros(3)
res = odeint(dY, y0, x)
plt.plot(x,res, '-')
```

as you can see the values are different by an offset of 0.02..

Am I missing something that results in this offset?

Comment: That notation could mean that you're using Euler forward integration for a single ODE for y OR integrating multiple coupled ODEs.  Which one is it?

Comment: @duffymo they are using the Euler forward integration for solving y

Comment: @MD' is this differential equation correct? Could you please give a reference from where you got it?

Comment: @SaulloCastro I added the original equation to the original post. The equation is calculating the concentration of a reactant in a pipe reactor.

Comment: Is this your equation?  http://www.cee.mtu.edu/~reh/courses/ce251/251_notes_dir/node3.html

Comment: @duffymo yes that is a form of my equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is a "coupled" ordinary differential equation (see "System of ODEs" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation).

The variable is a vector containing `y[0]`, `y[1]`, etc. To solve the ODE you must feed a vector as the initial condition and the function `dY` must return a vector as well.

I have modified your code to achieve this result:

```
def dY(y, x):
    a = 0.001
    yin = 1
    C = 0.01
    N = 1
    dC = C/N
    b1 = 0
    y_diff = -np.copy(y)
    y_diff[0] += yin
    y_diff[1:] += y[:-1]
    return (a/dC)*y_diff+b1*dC
```

I have written the part `y[i-1] - y[i]` as a NumPy vector operation and special cased the coordinate `y[0]` (that is the y1 in your notation but arrays start at 0 in Python).

The solution, using an initial value of 0 for all yi is

```
x = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
y0 = np.zeros(4)
res = odeint(dY, y0, x)
plt.plot(x,res, '-')
```

Comment: thank you for the implementation. However, I executed the code with a little modification to y0 and N such that the output matches the results of my validation table. See Edit2 where I elaborate on what I have.